# SQL - How to GROUP output of one query using sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
    to_char(date(recorded_time), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS activity_date,
    status,
    count(status) AS count
FROM cart_log
WHERE id = 1::integer
    AND recorded_time > current_timestamp - interval '14 days'
    AND action = 'sell'
GROUP BY activity_date, action, status
ORDER BY activity_date DESC
```

-- OUTPUT of above SQL --

```
activity_date   status  count
"2019-09-02"    "f"     4
"2019-09-02"    "s"     10
"2019-09-01"    "s"     2
"2019-09-01"    "f"     6
"2019-08-31"    "s"     4
"2019-08-27"    "s"     1
"2019-08-26"    "f"     3
```

> Here "s" means Success & "f" means Fail

Expected Output:

```
activity_date   s_count   f_count
"2019-09-02"    10          4
"2019-09-01"    2           6
"2019-08-31"    4           0
"2019-08-27"    1           0
"2019-08-26"    0           3
```

Note: If the any opposite status count is not present for that date I want to display default 0 (Zero) against that date, so that I can render proper BAR chart.

I am running Postgres 9.4 & planning to upgrade to Postgres 11, How Do wrap output of above query to get desired output and the same sql works with postgres 9.4 & Postgres 11 both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT to_char(recorded_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS activity_date,
       SUM( (status = 's')::int ) as s_count,
       SUM( (status = 'f')::int ) as f_count
FROM cart_log
WHERE id = 1::integer AND
      recorded_time > current_timestamp - interval '14 days' AND
      action = 'sell'
GROUP BY activity_date
ORDER BY activity_date DESC;
```

Or, you can use `filter` . . . it was added in Postgres 9.4:

```
SELECT to_char(recorded_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS activity_date,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 's') as s_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'f') as f_count
FROM cart_log
WHERE id = 1::integer AND
      recorded_time > current_timestamp - interval '14 days' AND
      action = 'sell'
GROUP BY activity_date
ORDER BY activity_date DESC;
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm, I never thought it was that easy :)
Thanks a lot again!!